# jQuery datepicker time formating for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm having a bit of formatting problems:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Show_Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm}"
```

My Date Picker:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    $('#myDatePicker').val(dateText);
                    $('#date_search_form').submit();
                }
            });
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["he"]);
        });
```

Problem is I get mm/dd and not dd/mm like I want, tried changing it in both locations doesn't work.

Suggestions would be great!

**Edit**: I've tried setting dd/mm/yyyy at both places, it doesn't show the date at all like that

Comment: 'problem is I get mm/dd and not dd/mm like i want' you set the `dateFormat` option to `mm/dd/yy`

Comment: like i said try changing it, didnt see the effect taking place

Comment: Try moving the `setDefaults()` call before you define your datepicker. It may be overriding the settings you provide.

Comment: nop doesnt help